# iOS sound playback volume not respecting volume change or mute

Tags: iphone, ios, volume

This is my current code

```
void playSound(NSString* myString) {

    CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
    NSString *string = myString;
    CFURLRef soundFileURLRef;
    soundFileURLRef = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, 
                        (__bridge CFStringRef) string, CFSTR ("wav"), NULL);
    UInt32 soundID;
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileURLRef, &soundID);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);

}
```

It works, but it doesn't let you change the volume on the device or mute it with the mute switch. What is the simplest way to enable these features? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use [AVFoundation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/00_Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188)? If all you want is to play simple sound effects, it would be a much better choice as it is a higher level API.

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"file" ofType:@"mp3"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];

// Assuming audioPlayer is an ivar.
NSError *error;
audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1;

if (audioPlayer == nil)
    NSLog([error description]);             
else 
    [audioPlayer play];
```

`AVAudioPlayer` should respect the volume settings of the user.

Comment: how do I declare audioPlayer?

Comment: Okay I did that but now I am getting this Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter'

Comment: You have to learn to debug your code and to interpret error messages. Read what it says. In the `NSURL` line your parameter is `nil`. Your only parameter is `filePath`, so that's `nil`. Then you go to the documentation of [`pathForResource:ofType:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSBundle/pathForResource:ofType:) and see under **Return Value**: "The full pathname for the resource file or `nil` if the file could not be located." Your file name is wrong or the file is missing.

Comment: This is the path of folders where my sound is located ----- PROJECTNAME -> Supporting Files -> My Sounds -> and then the file name is called cow.wav and i have this pathForResource:@"cow" ofType:@"wav"

Comment: I have no idea what a target is, please clarify?

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/XcodeConcepts/Concept-Targets.html

Comment: So how would I add a target to a project I already have? I clicked add target under build phases but it seems like that is just another project.

Comment: Idk if this helps but the file I want to play is in the CopyBundleREsources